# get an object's property name using its value

Tags: javascript, object

i have an object

```
const alpha = {
  a: 'apple'
  b: 'bubble'
}
```

the goal is to get the property name by using only the value, for example, I want to use the string  apple to get the proberty name a in a form of a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following simple implementation will log the keys for `apple` in the console.

```
const alpha = {
  a: 'apple',
  b: 'bubble'
}


Object.entries(alpha).map(
        ([key, value]) => {
            if (value === 'apple'){
                console.log(key);
            }
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do something like this...

```
const alpha = {
  a: 'apple',
  b: 'bubble'
};

const selectKeys = (object, selector) => {
  let results = [];
  
  if (object != null) {
    results = Object.entries(object)
      .filter((e) => selector(e[1], e[0], e))
      .map((e) => e[0]);
  }
  
  return results;
};

const keys = selectKeys(alpha, (value) => value === 'apple');
console.log(keys);
```

This will just select all keys where the selector expression returns true. For your case thats just the name. Notice that this returns an array, because multiple keys can be returned. To get the first key simply use `keys[0]` or whatever.

You could get fancier and add higher order functions to make your selectors easier to read as well.

```
const byValue = (value) => (v) => v === value;
const a = selectKeys(object, byValue('apple'));
const a = selectKeys(object, byValue('bubble'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You would return a list of keys who's value matches the provided value. If you wanted the first match, just shift the value off the beginning of the result.

```js
const alpha = {
  a: 'apple',
  b: 'bubble'
};

const keysForValue = (obj, value) =>
  Object.entries(obj)
    .filter(([, val]) => val === value)
    .map(([key]) => key);
    
console.log('Key:', keysForValue(alpha, 'bubble').shift()); // Key: b
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below approach,

```
const alpha = {
  a: 'apple',
  b: 'bubble',
  c: 'bubble',
  d: 'orange',
  e: 'bubble'
}

const findKeyByValue = (obj, value) => {
  const arr = [];
  for (const prop in obj) {
    if(obj[prop] === value){
      arr.push(prop);
    }
  }
return arr;
};


findKeyByValue(alpha, 'bubble'); //[ 'b', 'c', 'e' ]
```